# How to indentify which image is clicked using ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to know the best way to identify the image I have clicked on a webpage so that I can replace another div with that image.

My html page looks like this -

```
<div id="image" >
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.image1_url,:width=>180, :height=>180), selection_path, remote: true %>
</div>
<div id="image2" >
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.image2_url,:width=>80, :height=>80), selection_path, remote: true %>
</div>
<div id="image3" >
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.image3_url,:width=>80, :height=>80), selection_path, remote: true %>
</div>
```

Now if I click on image2 then the image shown in div with id="image" should get replaced with `@product.image2_url`. I've created a `product.js.erb` file which looks like the following -

```
$('#image').html("<%= escape_javascript image_tag(@product.image1_url,width: '250', height: '250') %>");
```

The above js works for one image., but I'm unable to write the correct jquery code to identify which image is clicked. How do I identify which element is clicked. I think it's quite is but I'm new to jquery/javascript. Also let me know any useful resources that can help me to learn to code in js.erb files.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: give all your div's a class like 'images'. afterwards apply the onclick handler $('.images').on('click', function() { $(this) //this returns the element you just clicked on. you can use $(this).html.... });

Answer (score 1):

You can find closest div of `this` (current js object):

```
$('img').click(function() {
  clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div');
  clickedDiv.html( ... ); // do whatsoever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mixing javascript with rails then you need a way to mix your client code with your server code.

One way is set a param in your `selection_path` to identify what image is clicked, ie: `selection_path(image_id: '2'` then in your js.erb you can do something like: `$("#image<%=params[:image_id]%>").html(...)`

A second way is use the ujs callbacks (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) to set variables in js that you can use the in your js.erb file

Answer (score 0):

***This is my working example where i dont use a new partial though...i have all images on same page where main image is on top and small images are listing below in thumbnails.***.suppose your html file has main image and horizontal listing of images where any img clicked replaces `src` of main image using `class` selector

```
<!-- main image that should be replaced on click of any listing images below-->
 <div class="row">
<%= image_tag @image.image_photos.first.avatar.expiring_url(10),:class=>"img-responsive main_image_show_image",:style=>"margin: 0px auto;"%>
</div> 

<!-- this is the horizontal thumbnail image listing row which is clickable and replaces the above main image -->
 <hr>
<div class="row">
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
<% @image.image_photos.each do |i|%>
<li style="width:100px;">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="thumbnail change_and_add_new_show_image">
<%= image_tag i.avatar.expiring_url(10),:class=>"img-responsive ",:style=>"margin: 0px auto;"%>
</a>
</li>
<%end%>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.change_and_add_new_show_image').click(function(){
var img_src=$(this).find("img").attr("src");
$(".main_image_show_image").attr("src",img_src);
})//method ends
})//document ends
</script>
```

so all you do is **replace** `src` of main image with the `one clicked`